# Wrong media location using Django management command

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm downloading an image and saving it to a models image field, on a separate media app. Everything was working fine while the code was in a view but soon as I moved the code into a management command I can't get the image to save into the separate media location. Before it was correctly saving to `/home/me/webapps/myapp_production_media/images` now the files are being saved incorrectly to `/home/me/webapps/myapp_production_django/src/media/images`

command:

```
download_image('temp', model_instance.image, new_image)

def download_image(name, image, url):
    input_file = StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    output_file = StringIO()
    img = Image.open(input_file)
    if img.mode != "RGB":
        img = img.convert("RGB")
    img.save(output_file, "JPEG")
    image.save(name+".jpg", ContentFile(output_file.getvalue()), save=False)
```

model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
```

I've added `myapp_production_media/images` path to the `name+".jpg"` but it doesn't change anything. I'm guessing this is happening because the image field in the model doesn't access the media_root in settings.py (as the code is a management command)?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`?

Comment: @TomasWalch ah this was the problem thanks, I'm using django-configurations and wasn't using --configuration=Prod when running the management command. If you want to make your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: added below, glad I could help :)

Comment: @VladimirDanilov I found that code on SO from someone else trying to download images. Seems to work but if `BytesIO` is preferable I'll change it

Comment: @KingFu Sorry, I thought you use Python 3. My advice is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check that you are using the same settings file when running the management command. Production settings are usually not configured as default and in these cases need to be given on command line.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing the following at the beginning of the command file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
```

where app.setting is where the setting.py resides.